# Canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data

Tags: javascript, canvas, cross-domain

I have a website with a canvas where I load an image by asking visitors to upload it via an upload button. I'm aware of the cross-origin issue so I take the image, I upload it via ajax using this plugin : [jQuery Form Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/)
then I extract the image data in base64 and after that I send it to the canvas to load the image to it. With this process I was expecting to avoid the cross origin data issue but it seems it worked for some browsers and not for others in mac for instance where I get Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D' : The Canvas has been tained by cross-origin data. Any help on this please.

Thanks.

[image: Canva Error]

HTML code for the image upload is:

```
<form id="ajax_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
<input id="upload-input" name="file" class="file" type="file">
</form>
```

Javascript functions to handle the upload via ajax and image insertion to the canvas:

```
function Editor(canvas, options) {
    this.canvas = canvas;
    this.ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    this.valid = false;
    this.options = options || {};
    this.enabled = true;
    this.translate = {x: 0, y: 0, dx: 0, dy: 0};
    this.imageRotationPoint = {x: 0, y: 0};
    this.scale = 1;
    this.scaleExtra = 1;
    this.rotate = 0;
    this.rotateExtra = 0;
    // Currently being rotated
    this.inRotation = false;
    // Set up the initial event handlers
    this.mousedown = Editor.handleMouseDown.bind(this);
    this.mouseup = Editor.handleMouseUp.bind(this);
    this.mousemove = Editor.handleMouseMove.bind(this);
    this.canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', this.mousedown);
    this.canvas.addEventListener('touchstart', this.mousedown);
    // Handle touch events
    var that = this;
    this.imgrotate = 0;
    var pinchRotateImg = this.canvas;
    Transform(pinchRotateImg);
    var initScale = 1;
    var currentRotation = this.imgrotate;
    new AlloyFinger(pinchRotateImg, {
        rotate: function (evt) {
            currentRotation += evt.angle;
            that.inRotation = true;
            that.rotate = currentRotation;
            that.valid = false;
        },
        multipointStart: function () {
            initScale = pinchRotateImg.scaleX;
        },
        pinch: function (evt) {
            var scale = initScale * evt.zoom;
            if (scale > 4) {
                scale = 4;
            }
            if (scale < 0.25){
                scale = 0.25;
            }
            that.scaleExtra = scale;
            that.valid = false;
        },
        pressMove: function (evt) {
            that.inRotation = false;
            evt.preventDefault();
        }
    });
    this.initialSetup();
    setInterval(function () {
        that.draw();
    }, 30);
};

Editor.prototype.getTheFace = function () {
        var w = this.canvas.width;
        var h = this.canvas.height;
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        canvas.width = w;
        canvas.height = h;
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
        // Position the image
        ctx.save();
        var img = this.options.image;
        ctx.translate(this.translate.x + this.translate.dx, this.translate.y + this.translate.dy);
        ctx.scale(this.scale * this.scaleExtra, this.scale * this.scaleExtra);
        ctx.rotate((this.rotate + this.rotateExtra) * Math.PI / 180);
        // Draw the background image
        ctx.drawImage(img, this.imageRotationPoint.x, this.imageRotationPoint.y, img.width, img.height);
        // Reset the state
        ctx.restore();
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
        // Create a new canvas with the template
        var canvas2 = document.createElement('canvas');
        var ctx2 = canvas2.getContext('2d');
        canvas2.width = w;
        canvas2.height = h;
        ctx2.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
        ctx2.drawImage(this.options.template, 0, 0, w, h);
        // Remove the line in the middle
        ctx2.clearRect(555, 630, 400, 5);
        // Cut the face out
        ctx.drawImage(canvas2, 0, 0, w, h);
        // Cut out the face part of the image, and put it on a separate canvas
        var cut = ctx.getImageData(550, 458, 410, 450);
        var canvasFace = document.createElement('canvas');
        var ctxFace = canvasFace.getContext('2d');
        canvasFace.width = 410;
        canvasFace.height = 450;
        ctxFace.putImageData(cut, 0, 0);
        return canvasFace.toDataURL();
};

    // Handle uploading files
$('#upload-input').on('change', function () {
    processFiles(this.files);
});
function processFiles(files) {
    for (var i = 0, len = files.length; i < len; ++i) {
        var file = files[i];
        // Only process images
        if (file.type.match(/^image\//)) {
            var options = {
                url: '/upload',
                type: 'post',
                success: afterSuccess
            };
            $("#ajax_form").ajaxSubmit(options);
        }
    }
}
function afterSuccess(response) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function () {
        editor.updateImage(img);
    },
    img.src = response.dataURL;
}
```

The PHP upload script :

```
public function upload() {
    $this->upload->do_upload('file');//This is codeignitor upload library 
    $b64str = base64_encode(file_get_contents($this->upload->data('file_name')));
    $dataURL = "data:".$this->upload->data('file_type').";base64,".$b64str;
    $this->output->set_content_type('application/json')->set_output(json_encode(array('dataURL' => $dataURL)));
    }
```

Comment: Just to clarify it, are you using the same domain for all files?

Comment: And other question, have you clear the browser cache in all browsers?

Comment: Yes, I use one unique domain and yes I clear cache everytime

Comment: And, other question, you upload the image to the server and then you load the image from the server and that image is the one you draw in the canvas, right?

Comment: yes, I load to the canvas the base64 info of the image that is now hosted on my server

Comment: can you try to save the image as-is in your server, and set the image.src to the url in your server? You don't need to modify the uploading thing to try first, it would be enough to set img.src = [hereSomeImageInYourServer] in the afterSuccess function.

Comment: Oh, and to ensure the canvas haven't been tainted, could you try also to getImageData without drawing the image at all?

Comment: It works too if I put the image url from the server to the canvas, but as I said, the cross origin issue does not happen all the time so I don't know if puting the image url will fix it instead of the base64 data. For the second part of the question I don't understand what you meant. Thanks

Comment: Please keep trying the image url enough to feel sure if that is a solution (or it keeps failing time to time). About the other question, don't worry about it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll post a comment if an error happened

Comment: I really hope you can make it work!